# entity framework 6 Dbgeometry.WellKnownValue.WellKnownBinary not being populated

Tags: c#, entity-framework, spatial

I am using entity framework 6 for crud operations including a DbGeometry property. The property holds a polygon created from WellKnownText.

```
DbGeometry.PolygonFromText("POLYGON((1.00 1.00, 1.00 80.00, 80.00 80.00, 80.00 1.00, 1.00 1.00))", 27700);
```

When saving the entity binary data is stored in the spatial database. However when retrieving WellknownValue is being populated with the WellKnownText, however the Dbgeometry.WellKnownValue.WellKnownBinary property is null

(Would post image here but not enough reputation points :( )

Surely this should of been populated from the binary in the database. I have tried setting the field by the AsBinary() method with no success.

**UPDATE**

Thanks John but unfortunately this is not working either. I have tried:

```
Property.WellKnownValue.WellKnownBinary = Property.AsBinary();
```

which still leaves Property.WellKnownValue.WellKnownBinary as null using the QuickWatch window

Also I have tried

```
byte[] byteVariable = Property.AsBinary();
```

This does create a 93 byte long byte array I have pasted below, however this seems very empty for what it should contain.

1,3,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,240,63,0,0,0,0,0,0,240,63,0,0,0,0,0,0,240,63,0,0,0,0,0,0,84,64,0,0,0,0,0,0,84,64,0,0,0,0,0,0,84,64,0,0,0,0,0,0,84,64,0,0,0,0,0,0,240,63,0,0,0,0,0,0,240,63,0,0,0,0,0,0,240,63,

If I then try to assign that byte array to the WellKnownBinary:

```
 Property.WellKnownValue.WellKnownBinary = byteVariable
```

Property.WellKnownValue.WellKnownBinary is still shown as null using the QuickWatch window

I am seriously running out of ideas :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why the `DbGeometry.WellKnownValue.WellKnownBinary` is NULL but it shouldn't matter, the data is stored in SQL in binary format.

You're actually almost there, except `DbGeometry.AsBinary()` is a getter, not a setter.

So if you do actually need it's value, simply use `DbGeometry.AsBinary()` to retrieve the value (as a Byte Array).

Comment: Thanks for your help John, I have tried what you have suggested but unfortunately without much success

Comment: @RichardWatts OK, but why do you NEED that property to be NOT NULL?  Can you elaborate for me?

Comment: Other software which will be interfacing with mine requires that binary data (Arc Objects). Due to performance concerns the WellKnownText is not enough and the WellKnownBinary is needed.

Comment: @RichardWatts OK, so why can you not send them the result of DbGeography.AsBinary() which is a byte array that can be easily serialised and compressed for transmission?  Additionally, I'm not sure that WellKnownText values are THAT slow in comparison but I must say I haven't done that many comparison tests on the two.

Comment: Thanks John, we ended up running a conversion on the client. Thanks for your input, strange the property wasn't populated, maybe a EF bug!